# Como separar uma letra de uma character em SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where

Tenho uma variável do tipo character varying(17) e preciso separar um dos caracteres, por exemplo a terceira letra, e utiliza-la para filtra.
Por exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM fnord
WHERE terceira(illuminati) = "a"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que o mais simples será (utilizando a dica da 3ª letra):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    fnord
WHERE   substr('illuminati', 3, 1) = 'a'
```

O 1º parâmetro é a `string` que quer validar, o 2º é o índice e o 3º é a quantidade de caracteres que pretende "retirar" (é opcional).

Comment: Só um detalhe: o terceiro parâmetro se não especificado equivale a todos os caracteres restantes da string. Veja: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/18657

Comment: Certo, por isso indiquei que seria opcional.

Answer (score 2):

Para isso existe a função [substr](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html)

> substr(string, from [, count])
>   substr('alphabet', 3, 1) retorna  p (terceira posição , um caractere)

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/949019/1)